# What is the correct replacement for a 'band' of snakes?

Tags: word-request, collective-nouns

What is the correct replacement for a 'band' of snakes?

Comment: Group nouns are bed, den, pit or nest, apparently. None of those sound active, though.

Comment: I've also seen that they can be called as a *nightmare*.

Comment: Snakes don't group out of the nest so I don't believe there would be a name for a group of snakes.

Comment: Presumably you are asking for the *[term of venery](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49540)* for snakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A group of snakes are generally referred to as :

1. > A Den of snakes.
2. > A Nest of snakes.
3. > A Pit of snakes.
4. > A Bed of snakes.
5. > A Knot of snakes.

But generally snakes do not hang around in groups. You do not find them together in a natural habitat unless its in a nest to hatch eggs or when they are mating.